# DynamicResource ResourceKey not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamicresource

How can I reference _brush_backcolor001 in another ResourceDictionary?
Like this it's not working:

```
<ResourceDictionary 

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="_rd001">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="_brush_backcolor001">#FF8FBC8F</SolidColorBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <Style TargetType="Paragraph" x:Key="_stylePara001">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="_brush_backcolor001" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use resources from other resource dictionaries you can merge them by specifying [`ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx)

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="_brush_backcolor001">#FF8FBC8F</SolidColorBrush>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Paragraph" x:Key="_stylePara001">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="_brush_backcolor001" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

where `_brush_backcolor001` can be extracted to separate `RecourceDictionary` file and then referenced via `Source` property

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="path/to/separate/resouce/file.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```